# Android and test simplecalc in jUnit

Tags: android, junit

I have a problem with test in jUnit.
This is my test class:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonResult, buttonPlus;
    EditText resultConsole;
    private static final String FIRSTVALUE = "12";
    private static final String SECONDVALUE = "21";
    private static final String RESULT = "33.0";
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super("com.example.simpletest", MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
            setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
            mainActivity = getActivity();
            button1 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button4 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            button5 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button5);
            button6 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button6);
            button7 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button7);
            button8 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button8);
            button9 = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button9);
            buttonResult = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.buttonResult);
            buttonPlus = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
            resultConsole = (EditText) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }
    String result;
    public void testPlus(){
            mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    assertTrue(button1.performClick());
                    assertTrue(button2.performClick());
                    assertTrue(buttonPlus.performClick());
                    assertTrue(button2.performClick());
                    assertTrue(button1.performClick());
                    assertTrue(buttonResult.performClick());

                    result =  resultConsole.getText().toString();
                    assertTrue(!result.equals(0));
                    assertEquals(result, RESULT);


                }
            });


    }

}
```

and this is tested class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, buttonResult, buttonPlus;
    EditText resultConsole;
    String result = "";
    Double variable = 0.0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        buttonResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonResult);
        buttonPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
        resultConsole = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

       button1.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button2.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button3.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button4.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button5.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button6.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button7.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button8.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       button9.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(onClick);
       buttonResult.setOnClickListener(onClick);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                result += button1.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                result += button2.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                result += button3.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                result += button4.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                result += button5.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                result += button6.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button7:
                result += button7.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button8:
                result += button8.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.button9:
                result += button9.getText().toString();
                resultConsole.setText(result);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonPlus:
                if(!result.equals("")){
                variable += Double.parseDouble(result);
                resultConsole.setText(variable.toString());
                result = "";
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonResult:
                if(!result.equals("")){
                variable += Double.parseDouble(result);
                resultConsole.setText(variable.toString());
                result = "";
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

This is simple calculator. I want to test result and equals results. To check result I want to click on buttons and check text from editText. But something is wrong because I don't get error in `testPlus()` even if I set `RESULT` on `22`. Result after click buttons from that method should set text in edit view on 33.0, so text after click buttons from that method and RESULT is different so test should don't pass. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is solution:

```
public void testPlus(){
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                assertTrue(button1.performClick());


            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                assertTrue(button2.performClick());


            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                assertTrue(buttonPlus.performClick());


            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                assertTrue(button2.performClick());


            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                assertTrue(button1.performClick());


            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                assertTrue(buttonResult.performClick());



            }
        });
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        String result =  resultConsole.getText().toString();
        assertTrue(!result.equals(0));

        assertEquals(RESULT, result);
}
```